# Prove identity involving $\operatorname{lcm}(x, y, z)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm

I received this problem to prove that:
$$
\operatorname{lcm}(x, y, z) = \frac{xyz}{\operatorname{gcd}(x, y, z)\cdot\operatorname{gcd}(\operatorname{lcm}(x, y), \operatorname{lcm}(x, z), \operatorname{lcm}(y, z))}
$$
Knowing that: $$\operatorname{lcm}(x, y) = \frac{xy}{\operatorname{gcd}(x, y)}$$

I started saying that:
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{lcm}(x, y, z) &= \operatorname{lcm}(\operatorname{lcm}(x, y), z)\\
&= \frac{z\cdot\operatorname{lcm}(x, y)}{\operatorname{gcd}(z, \operatorname{lcm}(x, y))}\\
&=\operatorname{lcm}(x, y, z)\\
&= \frac{z\cdot\operatorname{lcm}(x, y)}{\operatorname{gcd}(z, \operatorname{lcm}(x, y))}\\
&= \frac{xyz}{\operatorname{gcd}(x, y)\cdot\operatorname{gcd}(z,\operatorname{lcm}(x, y))} 
\end{align*}

And I got stuck, how do I prove that it equals:

$$
\frac{xyz}{\operatorname{gcd}(x, y, z)\cdot\operatorname{gcd}(\operatorname{lcm}(x, y), \operatorname{lcm}(x, z), \operatorname{lcm}(y, z))}
$$

Comment: What sometimes works in these problems is to let $x = \prod_{p}{p_i}^{e_i}$ etc and take $\max$ and $\min$ of the exponent.

Comment: I tried, if $x = \prod_{s}{p_i}^{a_i}, y = \prod_{s}{p_i}^{b_i},  z = \prod_{s}{p_i}^{c_i}$, I have in the exponents: $a + b + c - min(a, b) - min(c, max(a, b))$

Comment: Check the last 2 term of your expression as it doesn't seem symmetric in $a, b, c$ (though it might end up being symmetric?).

Comment: I have those 2 terms as $ - \min(a, b, c) - \min ( \max(a, c ) , \max (a, b) , \max (b, c) )$. You then want to verify that it equals the LHS, which can be easily done via cases (or alternatively recognizing that we're subtracting the smallest and second smallest term, hence left with the largest term).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Lemma:** For any nonnegative integers $a_i, b_i, c_i$, we have
$$\mathrm{min}\{\mathrm{max}\{a_i, b_i\},\mathrm{max\{b_i, c_i}\},\mathrm{max\{c_i, a_i}\}\} + \mathrm{min}\{a_i, b_i, c_i\} +\mathrm{max}\{a_i, b_i, c_i\} = a_i + b_i + c_i.$$

**Proof:** Without loss of generality, we can impose an arbitrary ordering, say $a_i \leq b_i \leq c_i$. Then $$\mathrm{min}\{\mathrm{max}\{a_i, b_i\},\mathrm{max\{b_i, c_i}\},\mathrm{max\{c_i, a_i}\}\} + \mathrm{min}\{a_i, b_i, c_i\} +\mathrm{max}\{a_i, b_i, c_i\} = \mathrm{min\{b_i, c_i, c_i\} + a_i + c_i = b_i + a_i + c_i = a_i + b_i + c_i}. \square$$

Now, we have
$$\max\{a_i, b_i, c_i\} = a_i + b_i + c_i - \mathrm{min}\{\mathrm{max}\{a_i, b_i\},\mathrm{max\{b_i, c_i}\},\mathrm{max\{c_i, a_i}\}\} - \mathrm{min}\{a_i, b_i, c_i\}$$
so that
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{lcm}(x, y, z) = \prod_{p}p_i^{\max\{a_i, b_i, c_i\}} &= \frac{\prod_p p_i^{a_i 
 + b_i + c_i}}{\prod_p p_i^{\mathrm{min}\{\mathrm{max}\{a_i, b_i\},\mathrm{max\{b_i, c_i}\},\mathrm{max\{c_i, a_i}\}\}} \prod_{p} p_i^{\mathrm{min}\{a_i, b_i, c_i\}}} \\ &= \frac{xyz}{\operatorname{gcd}(x, y, z)\cdot\operatorname{gcd}(\operatorname{lcm}(x, y), \operatorname{lcm}(x, z), \operatorname{lcm}(y, z))}
\end{align*}
as desired. $\blacksquare$

Comment: In questions like this, is it common to check the right hand side and prove a certain part by ordering the values? (a, b, c, in your proof of the lemma)

Comment: @LucasSaito yeah, by imposing an ordering on the values, we can give an actual value to the max and min expressions (this works by symmetry).

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to do it one prime at a time.

Let $p$ be a prime that divides one or more of $x,y$ or $z$, and let $k_x$ be the highest power so that $p^{k_x}|x$ and $k_y$ the highest power so that  $p^{k_y}|y$ and so on (note: some of these may be equal to $0$).

By symmetry we can assume $k_x \le k_y \le k_z$.  If that seems too glib, just relabel that $w = $ the $x,y$ or $z$ where $p$ divides by the lowest power, $u=$ the $x,y$ or $z$ where $p$ divides by the middle power, and $v = x,y$ or $z$ where $P$ divides by the highest.

The highest power of $p$ that divides $lcm(x,y,z)=lcm(w,u,v)$ is $p^{\max(k_x,k_y,k_z)} = p^{k_v}$.

The highest power of  $p$ that divide the RHS of the equation id $p^{(k_x+ k_y + k_z)- [\min(k_x,k_y,k_z) + \min(\max(k_x,k_y),\max(k_x,k_z),\max(k_y,k_z)]}=$

$p^{(k_w+ k_u + k_v)- [\min(k_w,k_u,k_v) + \min(\max(k_w,k_u),\max(k_w,k_v),\max(k_u,k_v)]}=$

$p^{(k_w+ k_u + k_v)- [k_w + \min(k_u,k_v,k_v)]}=$

$p^{(k_w+ k_u + k_v)- [k_w + k_u]}=$

$p^{k_v}=$

$p^{\max(k_x,k_y,k_z)}$.

So for every $p$ that divides any of $x,y,z$ the power of $p$ that divides both sides is exactly the same!

So do that for every prime that divides $x,y,$ or $z$ and the result follows.